# What does the free variable indicate in this scenario?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Imagine there are three suggested levels of donation with the
>   associated dollar amounts:
>   bronze (\$1), silver (\$5), and gold (\$10).
>   You collect a total of \$121 with a total of 37 donations. Describe the
>   claims you can make about the data you collected.

I took the rref of the matrix A =

```
 1     5    10   121
 1     1     1    37
```

which resulted in the third column missing a pivot. Is the third variable free? Meaning there are infinite combinations that satisfy these conditions?

The rref of the matrix : ans =

```
1.0000         0   -1.2500   16.0000
     0    1.0000    2.2500   21.0000
```

I could create a vector that replaces x1 and x2 in terms of x3. Not exactly sure what this will provide. Any insight or advice is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I think the donations are assumed to be non-negative integers, no? Since the third column has $4$ in the denominator, the free variable (=number of gold donations) can be $0$, $4$ or $8$.

Answer (score 1):

You have two equations, which means two affine planes in 3D.
$$
a_{i1} x_1 + a_{i2} x_2 + a_{i3} x_3 = y_i \iff \\
a_i \cdot x = y_i
$$

The (real-valued) solutions consist of the possible intersection cases:

- two parallel, disjoint planes: no solution
- two parallel, identical planes: infinite many solutions, 2 free variables
- two planes intersect in one line: infinite many solutions, 1 free variable

You have normal vectors $a_1 = (1, 0,-1.25)$ and $a_2=(0, 1, 2.25)$ which point in different, non-parallel directions, so the planes are not parallel, that leaves the last case.

**Update:**

Let us have a look at your specific case:

[image: the scene]

The $x_1$-axis is rendered in red, the $x_2$-axis in green and the $x_3$-axis  in blue.

The yellow plane represents all points of the plane given by the first initial equation $x_1 + 5 x_2 + 10 x_3 = 121 = n_1 \cdot x$, $n_1 = (1,5,10)^T$.

The green plane represents all points of the plane given by the second initial equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 37 = n_2 \cdot x$, $n_2 = (1,1,1)^T$.

The red diagonal line is the intersection of those two planes, every point is a real-valued solution of the system.

If we want to restrict the solutions to whole numbers, that red diagonal has to be intersected with the grid points of $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

If one further accepts only non-negative solutions, one has to add constraints $x_i \ge 0$, which are the affine half-spaces towards the viewer, bounded by the planes $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 0$ (both rendered in turqoise) and the plane $x_3 = 0$ (the grey bottom plane, with a net on it).

The blue dots are the three non-negative integer solutions found by WolframAlpha:
$$
P_1 = (16, 21, 0)^T \\ 
P_2 = (21, 12, 4)^T \\
P_3 = (26, 3, 8)^T 
$$

Comment: Perhaps, but when the numbers are constrained to whole numbers such as pennies, nickels, and dimes. There must be a finite number of solutions that satisfy the equation..Correct?

Comment: I assumed from your approach, that you were looking for solutions over the real numbers. You can restrict to whole numbers (positive, zero, and negative ones) and this would keep the above geometric reasoning intact, just an intersection with $\mathbb{Z}^3$ would be added, giving zero or infinite many solutions.

Comment: Further restrictions to non-negative numbers $x\ge 0$ add constraints in form of three half spaces, bound by the planes $x_i=0$. This allows finite many solutions. You should have a look at systems of linear Diophantine equations and/or integer linear programming for modeling and solution methods.

Comment: Using WA for this http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%2B5y+%2B+10z%3D121+and+x%2By%2Bz+%3D+37+and+x%3E%3D+0+and+y%3E%3D+0+and+z%3E%3D+0+over+the+integers&x=0&y=0